# Authentication against Active Directory.. Necessity of DirectorySearcher

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have below code to authenticate given username and password against Active Directory

```
DirectoryEntry entryInAbsg = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://....../DC=....,DC=..", username, password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            object nativeObject = entryInAbsg.NativeObject;
            authenticated = true;
```

is this sufficient to validate the user ? do i need to search the user again using DirectorySearcher ? 
The above username and password should be of Admin account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is sufficient to validate the user. But to perform a search you need to create an instance of DirectorySeacher and pass your DirectoryEntry object (entryinAbsg) plus any filters you may want to the constructor. Consider the example below in C#;

```
private DirectorySeacher GetDirectorySeacher(DirectoryEntry entryInAbsg)
{
      DirectorySearcher dirSeach = null;
      if(dirSearch == null)
      {
          try
          {
              dirSearch = new DirectorySeacher(entryInAbsg)
          }
          catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Authentification Failed!!!, Please Check.", "Error Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
          }
          return dirSearch;
     }
     else
     {
          return dirSearch;
     }
}
```

You may customize that according to your specific needs.